# javascript in twig file do not execute

Tags: javascript, symfony

when I try to put some script in a twig file , and finally they do not execute, for example:

```
{% block myJavascript %}
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
alert("test");
{% endblock %}
```

in my index.html.twig
I see it in the generate html code but it just do not execute. Anyone has some idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That doesn't look right.

What about:

```
{% block myJavascript %}
<script type="text/javascript">
  alert("test");
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

If js doesn't run, it can also mean there are errors triggered preceding this code, so make sure you check your browser's console.

For example, the first alert here will work, but the second will not:

```
<script>
  alert("this works");
  var = forced_error
  alert("this won't work");
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, i forgot to paste the rest: in fact , it's something like you said. And i think it is because of twig translator? i have not found anything before it.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue in **opencart twig** file, the script tag does not executed.

**OLD CODE DOES NOT WORK**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button-confirm').trigger('click');
     var input = $(this).find('input');
        input.trigger('click');
    });
    alert('test');
</script>
```

**NEW CODE**

i just remove **type="text/javascript"** from script section like below code and it worked for me

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button-confirm').trigger('click');
     var input = $(this).find('input');
        input.trigger('click');
    });
    alert('test');
</script>
```

I hope it will help :)

Comment: This is not true: [demo with type attribute](https://jsfiddle.net/1cz5huxk/) - [demo without type attribute](https://jsfiddle.net/1p3adwm8/)